# os.major() and os.minor() on block device incorrect?

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3.9.2 on Linux I try to find major and minor device numbers of a block device, e.g. `/dev/sda`.

For result checking I first note the expected result using shell utils:

```
$ ls -ltr /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Mar 15 13:34 /dev/sda
             major-----^  ^----minor

$ stat -c%t:%T /dev/sda
8:0
```

But then in python3:

```
python3 -c "import os ; print( os.major(os.stat('/dev/sda').st_dev) )"
0

python3 -c "import os ; print( os.minor(os.stat('/dev/sda').st_dev) )"
5
```

Major is `0` and minor is `5` according to python...?

The subject of many (if not all) questions similar to mine, is getting the major/minor numbers for some directory that resides on e.g. `/dev/sda2`. That somehow does get me the expected results:

```
python3 -c "import os ; print( os.major(os.stat('/etc').st_dev) )"
8
```

Can't find my mistake.  How can I get, using python, the major and minor numbers of a block device file like `/dev/sda`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `os.stat("/dev/sda").st_rdev`.

Comment: That's the answer. Still had not found this answer myself yet, but worked around it. Good to know though. Thanks.